# Incorporate Google Charts into a javascript object oriented web app

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to incorporate Google Charts into a javascript object oriented web app.  After the app is loaded - the idea is that the user clicks a certain button which builds/displays a certain chart.

I suspect that I have a scope problem.  Firefox/Firebug throws "InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character" which isn't very helpful.

Below is a snippet of what I'm trying to do.  Perhaps someone can point out some obvious problem with my attempt?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googlecharttest"></div>
</body>
</html>


BUTTON CLICK EVENT -> OBJchart.build_googlechart();

------------------
Javascript Snippet
------------------

OBJchart = new Fchart();

Fchart = function() { return {

    ...

    build_googlechart : function()
    {
        this.drawChart();

        // also tried this - with the same result.
        // google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], 'callback': this.drawChart});
    },

    drawChart : function()
    {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string','Topping');
        data.addColumn('number','Slices');
        data.addRows([['Mushrooms', 3],['Onions', 1],['Olives', 1],['Zucchini', 1],['Pepperoni', 2]]);

        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night','width':400,'height':400};

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('googlecharttest'));

        chart.draw(data,options);
    },

    ...
```

};};

Comment: How strange.... Just used the code inside drawChart and it's working fine... I got the graph. The error might be elsewhere. Can you provide more code and maybe see if you have a line number for the error ?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it Mateo.  I suppose that it's encouraging that you got drawChart() to run ok.  It's not throwing any other errors other than the InvalidCharacterError bits.  I'm hoping that conceptually it's valid to call google.load() once when the page loads - and then use it later on to create charts.  Knowing that is ok would be a great help.

Comment: Yes it is, that's What I did ! I think the problem may not be in the code you gave us.